# Why don't my media elements resize and clip properly when using UniformToFill?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, video, mediaelement

Why don't my media elements fill the screen correctly when I use the UniformToFill stretch? The mediaElement clips at the bottom if the window is wider than the mediaElement, and it clips at the right if the window is taller than the mediaElement.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window3"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Preview Window" Height="200" Width="600" WindowStyle="None" Background="Black" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"  MouseLeftButtonDown="Window3_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<Grid Focusable="False">
    <MediaElement Name="mediaElement2" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaOpened="mediaElement2_MediaOpened" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="289,-19,-11,-19" />
    <MediaElement Name="mediaElement1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaOpened="mediaElement1_MediaOpened" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-11,0,289,0"/>
</Grid>
```

In the program I use these commands to stretch it and use visual brushes to apply these videos to another window. The problem occurs in this window where the video/picture clip incorrectly

```
                window3.mediaElement1.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
                window3.mediaElement2.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the Stretch property to Stretch.Uniform instead of Stretch.UniformToFill.

If you want to fill the whole screen without maintaining relative dimensions, also try Stretch.Fill to stop clipping.

Comment: Hi, I have tested the stretch property and it seemed like it didn't work. Any idea on what are the other approaches? The <MediaElement> is inside <StackPanel>, I pre-defined height, and the width is auto.

Comment: If the height of the stack panel is set, the width/height of the `MediaElement` will be "desired width" by "predefined height." The desired width will probably be the native width of the media content. If you set Stretch to `Stretch.Uniform`, the height of the media element should be the native height if possible. If the native height of the media is greater than the predefined height, it's not clear if it would get cropped or if the auto width size would be shrunk by the uniform stretch. Provide more details on why "it didn't work" and I may be able to help more.

Comment: When I say it didn't work, I meant that there were no differences between the before and after. But it's okay, I got it solved. Thanks :)

Comment: @Joyce, how did you get it solve? Can you please share you solution with the rest of us facing the same issue?